help checking reliability of paper
I am doing some work on quinoline synthesis as biomass enhancement and as source for potential building blocks. (quinoline is now mostly extracted from coals...)
Found the following paper:
Sustainable synthesis of azobenzenes, quinolines and quinoxalines via oxidative dehydrogenative couplings catalysed by reusable transition metal oxide–Bi(III) cooperative catalysts
10.1039/d3cy00327b
The work looks really interesting as a mild alternative for the skraup for the synthesis of quinolines. The data almost looks to good to be true......
I found some mistakes in the introduction which starts to question the paper evenmore (mix up with lewis and bronsted acids).
Doing a quick scholar search also gives only 95 hits on the "oxidative dehydrogenative couplings" search term. The experimental/supporting information section is pretty minimal with only NMR as analytical prove.
The work is published open source and the following sentence describing the quinoline synthesis gives me good hope "These were completely unexpected results...". I kind of want to give it a try but we don't have metal salts in stock (small lab limited resources).
Do you guys have any advice/see any red flags? before I start ordering chemicals probably never use otherwise.

This paper? https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2023/cy/d3cy00327b  My first comment is that is published in a RSC journal so it will have been peer reviewed so I would be inclined to trust it.

"Do you guys have any advice/see any red flags? before I start ordering chemicals probably never use otherwise" is an opinion based question and this would likely to get closed for same reason.

Thanks for the replies and help! I have had some bad experiences with trying to reproduce work from some articles on improvements of the skraup reaction (but those were not RSC or ACS journals). Making me more cautious before believing the work done.  As this type of reaction i had not encountered before it rang some alarm bells in my head. Maybe I should not have to many second thoughts and give it try.
